# Data migration did not run last weekend

Tags: support, data-explorer

The migration of data to data.SE "didn't work" - dara is only up to 2013-10-06 (nine days ago as of now).

Could someone please look into it?

#### Update:

Still not run - 13 days old now.

BTW I've tweaked [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/125988/super-fast-last-data-migration-date) to bust the cache so it correctly shows the age in days.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/

Comment: It did run, it just looks like it must have failed for Stack Overflow for some reason.

Comment: Wait 6-8 weeks.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

The below is a dirty rotten lie preserved for posterity. As any clown who bothered to do more than check the FAQ would know, the most recent update for Stack Overflow is October 6th still, as evidenced by [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/142949/176022/).

---

[It seems to be fixed](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq):

> #### How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?
>
> The data is updated early every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was Oct 13 at 5:37.